# How to delete cart Item by SKU or productId in magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote, shopping-cart, quoteitem

I have retrieving all cart items and deleting the quote item by match with the product Sku,

Here is my code.

```
protected $checkoutSession;
protected $_itemModel;
protected $cart;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $itemModel
    { 
     $this->cart = $cart;
     $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
     $this->_itemModel = $itemModel;
     parent::__construct($context);
    }

 public function execute() {
       $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
                $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach($quoteItems as $item) {
                    $cartquote = $this->cart->getQuote();   

                    $productSku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
                    //$this->logger->info('ItemproductSku'.$productSku);
                    $checkExistedSKu  = $this->getExistedSKu($productSku);
                    if($checkExistedSKu){
                        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                        //$this->cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                        $this->_itemModel->load($item->getItemId())->delete();
                    }                       

                    $cartquote->updateItem($item->getId(), array( 'qty' => 1));
                    $cartquote->save();
                }

    public function getExistedSKu($productSku){
       $connection = $this->getConnection();
       $sql = "select * from custom_table where sku='".$productSku."'";
       $resultProduct = $connection->query($sql);
       $resultQuery = $resultProduct->fetchAll();

      if(!empty($resultQuery)){ 
        $parent_sku = $resultQuery[0]['parent_sku'];
        return true;
       }
      }else{
       return false;
      }
      }
```

I am getting the product Sku by itemId and checking against my custom table, if Product Sku present in the table I am deleting that quote item and updating all other Items by Qty 1.

This code is not working for me, can anyone look into it where i am doing wrong here,

Any help will be Appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for yourr comment

```
foreach($quoteItems as $item) {

                $productSku = $item->getSku();
                $checkExistedSKu  = $this->getExistedSKu($productSku);
                if($checkExistedSKu){
                    $item->delete();
                    continue;
                }                       

                $item->setQty(1);
                $item->save();
            }
$quote->collectTotals();
```

Comment: hi, can you update to my answer please, I need to set all remaining items as Qty 1, so i used above code, If i need to use your code, where to include that line, pls update me full answer

Comment: updated comment! pls check

Comment: $quote->save() is not required? at the end..

Comment: is it not required? I am going to use your code now

Comment: this is not working, Item deleting from the cart, but not showing in list, instead only total showing in the summary